# How do I let target image include qmake in Yocto?

Tags: qt, yocto, qmake, petalinux

I'd like to add qmake tool to target image with yocto.

So, I've tried the below:

```
# build/conf/local.conf
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "dev-pkgs"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "tools-sdk"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "petalinux-qt"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "petalinux-qt-extended"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qttools qttools-dev qttools-tools "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target "
```

As a result, it installed Qt libraries not qmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it as below!

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtbase-dev qtbase-mkspecs qtbase-tools "
```

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from the future.  When using Qt6, exclude qtbase-mkspecs.  It is included in qtbase-tools now.

Comment: Could you provide the source of this information?